# Check case in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm very new in Java and I got lab to do (is like a homework)

I'm trying to figure out how to write this method

```java
public int checkCase(String data)
```

The question from the site:

Java is case sensitive ... so just hitting the correct keys on the keyboard does not necessarily mean that you will get the correct variable or file name!!!!
Write the method that generates, stores (in an array) and lists (to standard output, one per line) ALL the possible names that can occur by pressing the correct keys but not necessarily the correct case (using the shift key or not) for an intended string whose value is read from standard input by the application and passed to this method as the parameter. For example, if the parameter value is "X.Y" this method will list the following (though not necessarily in this sequence):

```java
X.y
X.Y
X>Y
X>y
x.Y
x.y
x>Y
x>y
```

You should provide for possible data lengths of 1-8 characters and any alphabetic keys or the period key.

---

I'm not trying to ask for the answer directly to my homework or anything, but I just would like to get some guide or advice from you guys who understand better or have better knowledge of Java so that I can complete my homework.... if my professor have made it clear in the class I wouldn't bother asking here and waste anyone times in here, but really I'm lost at the moment.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @GaryF I have just write my class and reading the library about string in Java site.. :(

Comment: The solution you're looking for is *heavily dependent* on the layout of the keyboard.  There are different keyboard types that may not have a > as the shift-button of .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest method is loop through input string and for each character check its case using object wrapper under primitive `char` type - I mean `Character` class. It has such method as:

<strike>`Character.isUpperCase(char ch)`</strike>

**UPD:**
accroding to updated question's text, I have to change my answer.

Yes, I think you should use `Character` class for this goals. It has such methods as:
`Character.toUpperCase(char ch)` and `Character.toLowerCase(char ch)`.
You have to implement method, which will combine all possible cases for each char in the input string.

What about symbols `.`->`>` - this case you have to consider as a special case in your program.

Comment: and that would work even with the `.` to convert them to `>` ???

Comment: No, this one you should check manually as a special case. Well, actually your issue is not quite clear. Sorry I don't fully understand it.

Comment: [A quick reading of the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase(char)) indicates that this would only work on characters between A-Z, but doesn't ultimately solve . to >.  A custom solution would need to be implemented/fleshed out for that, but your answer is pretty spot-on.

Comment: @Andremoniy please excuse my English... I know and I'm trying to make it clear as much as I can, and now I have update my question where the instruction coming directly from my professor page.. I hope it will make it a bit clear.

Comment: This is much clear. But I should now update my answer.

Comment: @Makoto, I'm not native english-spoken man, so I don't quite understand what you mean by *your answer is pretty spot-on*.

Comment: @Andremoniy "Your answer is pretty spot-on", в данном случае, значит "твой ответ довольно точный", "попадающий в цель".